# Text content does not match server-rendered HTML in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I'm using i18next library for translating language. By default I was set English language and when I change the language to another language it’s working fine but after translating I tried to reload the page. I am getting an below error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
>
> See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
> Call Stack